# I am trying to bind a list to a combo box

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding, combobox

I am going to have a variety of lists that I am going to bind to a variety of comboboxes so I created a class called 'myValueList'

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class myValueList
    Public Property list As New List(Of myValueItem)

    Public Class myValueItem
        Public Property displayString As String
        Public Property valueString As String
    End Class

    Public Sub fill(ByVal mySqlString As String)
        Dim myconn As New myLib.mySQL
        myconn.setConnectionString("aUser", "aPassword", "aServer", "aDatabase")
        myconn.open()
        Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader = myconn.sendquery(mySqlString)
            Do While myReader.Read
                list.Add(New myValueItem() With {.displayString = myReader(0), .valueString = myReader(1)})
            Loop

        myconn.closeDispose()
    End Sub

End Class
```

And then I am trying to bind it to the combobox:

```
<ComboBox Height="22" Name="ComboBox54" Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=my_list}" DisplayMemberPath="displayString" SelectedValuePath="valueString"/>
```

Here is my mainwindow class:

```
Class MainWindow
    Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
        Dim myI As New initial
        Me.DataContext = myI
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is my initial class:

```
Public Class initial
Public Property my_list As New myValueList

    Public Sub New()
        my_list.fill("SELECT * from aTable")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Other bindings in this app are working so I suspect it is the way I am going about creating this list and then binding it. Any help / insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: isn't `list` the actual property that's a collection? if so shouldn't your Binding be `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=my_list.list}"`? your my_list is the class that seems to hold the list property but seems like your binding to the parent than the nested child. VB ain't something I'm familiar with so just a wild guess you could maybe try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Path is set to `my_list` (wich is an instance of `myValueList`), but the property on your class is named `list`, you should bind to `my_list.list`, which is the actual enumeration.

Comment: I have updated my question by adding my MainWindow class. I think this will show why I am binding to my_list

Comment: Then you should still bind to list via your myValueList class that you called my_list (my_list.list).

Comment: Thank you! as an additional question, does it make sense the way I am doing this? Do you think it should be done another way?

Comment: Depends what you want to achieve.